# Python square root problem with while loop, returns low decimal precision

Tags: python, math, precision

We need to find the square root approximation. The first approximation is

```py
x_0 = n / 2
```

, where n is the number that we are square rooting. The k approximation would then be:

```py
x_(k+1) = (x_k + n / x_k) / 2
```

The problem is that we need to find the square root approximation for which its square is within range of number `a`.
So in other words within `abs(n-a)`

So my try for this problem:

```py
def square_root_precision(n, a):
    approx_zero = n / 2
    approx_one = 0
    while approx_one ** 2.0 <= abs(n - a):
        approx_one = (approx_zero + n / approx_zero) / 2
        approx_zero = approx_one
    return approx_one
```

So the problem is that my function for `n = 2` and `a = 0.000001` returns `1.5` instead of `1.4142135623746899`

I went through the code many times. Is it a problem in precision of the function?

It would be great if we would solve this with only loops and no advanced functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`abs(n - a)` evaluates to `1.999999` and as soon as `approx_one` evaluates to `1.5` well, `1.5 * 1.5 >= 1.999999` so it returns your `1.5`.

You want to replace your `approx_one ** 2.0 <= abs(n - a)` with the absolute difference between your newly computed approximation and the last one being smaller than `a`.

For example:

```
def square_root_precision(n, a):
    approx_zero = n / 2
    approx_one = 0
    while True:
        approx_one = (approx_zero + n / approx_zero) / 2
        if abs(approx_one - approx_zero) < a:
            return approx_one
        approx_zero = approx_one

square_root_precision(2, 0.001)
```

> 1.4142135623746899

Comment: There is still one problem. The compiler says that it returns:  1.4142156862745097 instead of 1.4166666666666665 for (2, 0.01)

Comment: Then you want to return `approx_zero` instead of `approx_one`

Comment: It is very weird that it still doesnt want to say its a correct solution. The program says that everything is correct except one thing. And that the hint is : `7`

Comment: What's "it"? I don't understand the "hint" part

Comment: So the program where the solution is being veryfied says:
`The exercise doesnt have a valid solution.
  -Hint: 7`

I also dont understand what that should mean

Answer (score 3):

The condition for the loop should be `while abs(approx_one**2.0 - n) > a`.